# Interchange of limits of definite integral

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I could not understand one of the most magical property in Definite integral which is

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=-\int_{b}^{a} f(x)dx$$

My teacher has proved it in two ways:

Proof $1$.

By FTC $$\int_{b}^{a} f(x)dx=F(a)-F(b)=-\left(F(b)-F(a)\right)=-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Proof $2$.

if $a \lt b \lt c$ then

$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{b}^{c}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx$$

Put $c=a$ we get  $$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$$

Hence  $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=-\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$$

But in Proof $2$ how can we substitute $c=a$ when our assumption is $a \lt b \lt c$

If suppose $f(x)$ is above $X$ axis, then Area from $a$ to $b$ should be same as area from $b$ to $a$ right? But why negative sign should be multiplied.

For this my teacher answered that all distances measured along Negative to Positive X axis are positive and negative if we reverse the direction and he told that its a convention.

Comment: Proof 2 is also correct if you assume $a\leq b \leq c$

Comment: It depends on how you define the integral; if you define $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ for $a<b$, then $\int_b^af(x)\,dx=-\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is just another definition, so it needs no proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property $\int_{b}^{a} \cdots = -\int_{a}^{b} \cdots$ you mention, along with $\int_{a}^{a} \cdots = 0$, may be viewed as *definitions*. Together, these definitions guarentee the *cocycle condition*: If $f$ is integrable on some interval $I$, and if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are points of $I$, then
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx + \int_{b}^{c} f(x)\, dx + \int_{c}^{a} f(x)\, dx = 0.
$$
Intuitively, integrating over a closed loop gives the net change in $f$ at a point, namely zero.

Your teacher's arguments may be viewed as showing that *the cocycle condition is compatible with*:

1. The second fundamental theorem of calculus (a.k.a., the evaluation theorem).
2. The additivity property of the integral when the interval of integration is split.

Yet a third reason for the convention is:

3. If you divide an interval $[a, b]$ of integration into $n$ pieces of equal length $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}(b - a)$, then $\Delta x > 0$ if $a < b$ (i.e., you take positive steps when integrating left-to-right), and $\Delta x < 0$ if $a > b$ (i.e., you take negative steps when integrating right-to-left).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of an integral is NOT the area under a curve (this area is the intuitive idea behind it). It is the following limit (if it exists) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Riemann_integral

You can see that in the definition, it is assumed that $a<b$. To this point, calculating the integral from $b$ to $a<b$ does not make sense, since we didn't say what it was. It is later defined as

$\int_b^{a}f(x)dx = - \int_a^{b}f(x)dx$

This definition allows you to have plenty of nice formulas later.

With this definition, the property is obviously true.